# i don't know my worker role reboot

Tags: azure, worker, role

My worker role application works well on azure,when happen this error(File Server

> Resource Manager was unable to access the following file or volume:
>   'E:'.  This file or volume might be locked by another application
>   right now, or you might need to give Local System access to it.)

from windows event log,it reboot. so i do not know if caused by this error ?  anyone can help me ? thanks

Answer (score 1):

In Azure roles, the OS disk is d:, the resource disk is c:, and the application disk is either e: or f: depending on the latest deployment. You should never access the e: or f: drive by letter because of this switching around from deployment to deployment. Did you access the e: drive by letter?